# implement jquery show / hide toggles without accessing markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm seeking a better way to rewrite a simple show / hide jQuery toggle that could allow implementation based on using div selectors; and without modifying HTML markup (so without added class `.hidden` etc)

**I have a series of divs with class `.djseform_field` and no other selectors within; seeking to use only *this* class to turn these divs into show / hide jQuery toggles.**

Comment: and you have some code you might want to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // choose text for the show/hide link
    var showText='read more...';
    var hideText='hide';

    // initialise the visibility check
    var isVisible = false;

    // append show/hide links to the element directly preceding the element with a class of "djseform_field"
    $('.djseform_field').prev().append(' <a href="#" class="toggleLink">'+showText+'</a>');

    // hide all of the elements with a class of 'djseform_field'
    $('.djseform_field').hide();

    // capture clicks on the toggle links
    $('a.toggleLink').click(function() {
        // switch visibility
        isVisible = !isVisible;

        // change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
        if ($(this).html()==showText) {
            $(this).html(hideText);
        }

        else {
            $(this).html(showText);
        }

        // toggle the display
        $(this).parent().next('.djseform_field').slideToggle('slow');

        // return false so any link destination is not followed
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery should look like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-div').click(function(){

         $('.djseform_field').slideToggle( "slow", function() {

         });
});
```

Your Html should :

```
<div class="djseform_field">111</div>
<div class="djseform_field">222</div>
<div class="djseform_field" >333</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-div">toggle</a> <!-- Whatever you want to on click hide / show divs for refs i used a tag -->
```